Winsxs and sys32 folders are so large I can't reset the computer. How can I reduce these?
On a dumpster diving expedition I acquired an HP Stream netbook that I want to send to my niece. The previous owner didn’t factory reset it, and I didn’t know their password, so I couldn’t reset it myself. So instead, I did a clean reinstallation of the OS from a disk.
I set up a profile in my name to make sure it was working, now I want to factory reset it so she can set up her own website profile. But it says that there is not enough free disk space to download the OS for the reset. Only 5gb is available from a 32gb SSD.
This makes no sense, it’s fresh off a clean reinstall, so there should be no excessive files. I’ve added nothing, it’s just the system files on there, and I don’t want to go deleting those.
So I went poking around in the C drive, and I found the bulk of that excessive data was in the WinSxS folder. Everything I’ve read says not to delete this folder, as it contains information about previous versions and states I may want to roll back to. (But if I have no need to roll it back to previous versions, couldn’t I delete at least some of its contents?)
All the answers for this issue that I can find are very complicated. There are some command prompts for cleaning up the WinSxS folder, but none of these seem to work
I am running a component cleanup in Task Scheduler, but this has been running for six hours now.
Of course, I could do another clean reinstall, but if the data is there despite a clean reinstall, won’t another one exacerbate the issue?
Now, the WinSxS folder only accounts for 8.4gb, which is the bulk of this excessive data, but not all of it. I can't find the rest, but the system32 folder is unexpectedly large too.
I have also read that these folders tend to bloat, and that this is a necessary evil, but this bloat is rendering the machine unusable. There has to be a way!
I posted this question to the Windows help forum the other day, someone asked for screenshots, and advised me to download a program called Treesize. I did, but they never got back to me. So, here are those screenshots.
Screenshpt from disk management
Screenshot from Treesize 1
Screenshot from Treesize 2

You can always create a Windows 10 installation drive on another PC. // 32 GB is the bare minimum for Windows 10. You really do not want to use the system like that, get a larger SSD instead.

14GB WinSxS folder is perfectly normal. That’s exactly the size I would expect. You could try running the DISM to perform cleanup on the image but it seems easier to just reinstall Windows.

"32 GB is the bare minimum for Windows 10. You really do not want to use the system like that..."
Then why on earth would they ship a Windows 10 PC with only 32gb? Don't get me wrong, I know that's just the sort of thing they'd do. But they're selling a machine that could never be reset!
"...it seems easier to just reinstall Windows."
This would be the obvious answer, but I was worried that if the system files had bloated out after one reinstall, this would cause more bloat. But if 14gb is a reasonable size, then I'll give it a try.
